# Agency website with Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2

> I'm a just little bit curious.... I really want to know it is possible
>   to create a travel agency website with Magento platform So that people
>   can buy flights tickets online.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible and easy to do .

Comment: let me know if you have some questions or you need help  or need developer to do that for you